# Correct way to display errors when a record cannot be found in the database

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, zend-db

Currently, I have a model that has a method called getEmails($id=NULL). 
If $id == NULL getEmails() uses fetchAll($select)->toArray() to return all the records in the email table. In the view I have an if statement that checks to see if the array returned is an empty array. If it is, it displays an error letting the user know that there are no emails to display, otherwise it goes through a foreach() loop to display all the emails.

In this case, is it correct to be using the the if statement to check if the email array is emapty? Or should I be doing it another way?

If $id != NULL getEmails uses the following code to return just one record:

```
        $select->where('id=?',$id);
        $row = $this->fetchRow($select)
        if(!$row) throw new Exception('Could not find email with ID '.$id);
        else return $row->toArray();
```

As you can see, it throws an exception if the record could not be found.

I feel like there is a more unified way of displaying errors to the user when necessary.

Is it correct to throw an exception in the event that email with id $id cannot be found?

I'm trying to learn the "proper" way of doing things so thank you for all your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Zend Framework Flash Messenger to display that error message to the user.

In the controller you could use the following code:

```
$this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage("Could not find email with ID $id");
```

To display the message you could do the following:

In the controller you have to retrieve the messages:

```
$this->view->messages = $this->_helper->flashMessenger->getMessages();
```

In the view script you want to display them:

```
<?php if (count($this->messages)) : ?>
<ul id="messages">
<?php foreach ($this->messages as $message) : ?>
    <li><?php echo $this->escape($message); ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is a VERY basic example of how to use the flash messenger, but this would certainly get you on your way.

EDIT: After re-reading your question I realized (as I should have immediately) you were generating the error/exception from the model. You could test for null return value in the controller and send the message from there or you could create a session and store messages in there to be picked up and put into the flash messenger by the controller.